# xprop -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS hides maximized window

Tags: x11, cinnamon, window-management

I want to hide/show the title bar of a window with a key shortcut. So I got this script from a website (of which I don't have the URL anymore):

```
#! /bin/sh -x
winid=$(xprop -root | awk '/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW/ {print $5; exit;}')
current=$(xprop -id $winid | awk '/_MOTIF_WM_HINTS/ { sub(/,/,"",$5); print $5 }')
if [ -z $current ]; then
    current=0;
else
    current=$((1-$current))
fi

xprop -id $winid -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS "0x2, 0x0, $current, 0x0, 0x0"
```

I bound this script to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (I also tried <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> with the same effect). It works perfectly to toggle the window title on and off, except on maximized windows. When I run this script while the active window is maximized, the window hides completely. Undoing the operation shows the window again. But I don't want the window to hide, I only want the remove the window title bar.

I use Linux Mint 17 with Cinnamon 2.2.16.

Comment: It appears that firefox binds this key itself, which takes precedence over the Window Manager binding.

Comment: So I will have to find another keybinding? I will try that!

Comment: @BobDoolittle I binded the script on Super+F12 now and that seems to work. But only when firefox is not maximized. If it is maximized then I have the same effect (that the firefox window hides completely)

Comment: Can you try some key other than F12? At least as an experiment?

Comment: Where did you bind the key? In Cinnamon? @BobDoolittle Window manager bindings have precedence over application bindings: if the key is intercepted by the window manager, it isn't even seen by the application. Though going by your description, it appears that the key has its intended effect, the problem is that Firefox's window behaves differently from others when its properties are changed under Cinnamon. If you run the script manually, what happens?

Comment: I've edited my question because I noticed that it's not only firefox, but every window that has the weird effect when they are maximized. To answer @Gilles: I bind the keys in Cinnamon's settings panels (menu -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts)